# Skyrim frame rate issue for first 5 minutes of gameplay

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, framerate

I have quite a good computer with a core i7 processor, GeForce GT750, 16 GB RAM, so Skyrim should run smoothly all the time. However, for the first 5 minutes of gameplay the sound lags, the frame rate drops sometimes and after 5 minutes it runs smoothly. The only reason I can think of is that the gpu takes a while to boot up, and it is just using integrated graphics for the first five minutes but I'm probably wrong. What else can be the source of my problem?

Comment: Are you playing this on a laptop that has a hybrid Intel HD / Nvidia GPU?

Comment: What type of hard drive do you have? SSD, SATA? If SATA, what's the RPM.

Comment: Yes its a laptop with the nvidea gpu and intel hd graphics

Comment: Its not an ssd but i dont know how to check the rpm

Comment: Have you tried running Skyrim, forcing it to use the Nvidia chip and not the Intel one?

Comment: Are you running mods?

Comment: any chance you have some sort of active scan antivirus on your system?  it could be the first time your system touches the files it has to scan it first.  Try disabling it temporarily if you have one to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: MadMax, I right clicked skyrim and set the default to the to Nvidea GPU, Is that the same as forcing it to use nvidea gpu?

Comment: z, I use an antivirus so i'll try that, but its not the first time ive played skyrim,

Comment: This question is extremely hard to answer, but it might have to do with the game having to load things into a cache early on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not tech support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running an ENB, and in some cases a Reshade, they can take a while to load into system memory. Since the GT750 is a laptop model GPU, the VRAM can differ between OEM manufacturers. This can slow down the loading of ENB/Reshade, which can load quite a few texture packages to memory (VRAM).

Alternatively, if you are running a large number of texture mods, this can also cause a slow down in initial load time.

Finally, GeForce Experience is known to cause some crazy ini interference. If you are using it, I recommend uninstalling GeForce Experience, removing your ini files (make sure to take note of any specific mod required ini sequences), and let the game regenerate them. Make sure you then go into your NVidia control panel and reset your 3D Settings for Global and Skyrim back to default. Then work your way back to where you need to be for your graphics setup (e.g. vsync, frame loading, etc.).